# How to run a shell script on every request?

Tags: shell, nginx

I want to run a shell script every time my nginx server receives any HTTP request. Any simple ways to do this?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve with this? As you have explained it this could easily cause more issues.

Comment: I am on an RPi and I want one of the LEDs to blink whenever my server gets a request.

Comment: What back end language / framework are you using? Most back end languages should allow you to call a shell script.

Comment: My question is whether I can modify it within nginx. I don't want to call the shell script manually from PHP or any other language which I may run on every request.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your choosed answer as accepted ;)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can execute a shell script via `Lua` code from the nginx.conf file to achieve this. You need to have the [HttpLuaModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule) to be able to do this.

Here's an example to do this.

```
location /my-website {
  content_by_lua_block {
    os.execute("/bin/myShellScript.sh")
  } 
}
```

Comment: This seems to produce an nginx error... `[alert] 6807#0: waitpid() failed (10: No child processes)` - see http://serverfault.com/q/432609/86531

Comment: It seems that the standard error from `os.execute()` goes into the nginx error log, and any standard output is discarded. The `os.execute()` function returns the subprocess exit code, so this example would output an integer. Something based on `io.popen()` might work better for passing through the standard output from the subprocess.

Comment: There is also https://github.com/juce/lua-resty-shell but that requires an external daemon.

Comment: Usage of [content_by_lua](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#content_by_lua) is marked as discouraged, so I updated your answer accordingly

Comment: Can you get hold of POST or GET parameters from the request to pass the script?

Comment: Tried to install `openresty` to do so and nginx failed to start after that. Had to remove `openresty` to restart nginx

Answer (score 59):

I found the following information online at this address: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/2960191

This does expect that you have fcgiwrap installed on the machine. It is really as simple as:

```
sudo apt-get install fcgiwrap
```

Example script (Must be executable)

```
#!/bin/sh
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
NAME=`"cpuinfo"`
echo "Content-type:text/html\r\n"
echo "<html><head>"
echo "<title>$NAME</title>"
echo '<meta name="description" content="'$NAME'">'
echo '<meta name="keywords" content="'$NAME'">'
echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-type"
content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">'
echo '<meta name="ROBOTS" content="noindex">'
echo "</head><body><pre>"
date
echo "\nuname -a"
uname -a
echo "\ncpuinfo"
cat /proc/cpuinfo
echo "</pre></body></html>"
```

Also using this as an include file, not restricted to only shell
scripts.

```
location ~ (\.cgi|\.py|\.sh|\.pl|\.lua)$ {
    gzip off;
    root /var/www/$server_name;
    autoindex on;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/$server_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/$server_name$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

I found it extremely helpful for what I am working on, I hope it help you out with your RaspberryPI project.

Comment: See also https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/fcgiwrap/ and https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/fastcgiexample/

Comment: I needed to set the right permissions on the shell script `sudo chmod 755 /var/www/www.example.com/cpu.sh` (found here https://www.howtoforge.com/serving-cgi-scripts-with-nginx-on-centos-6.0-p2)

Comment: I found this article also quite helpful for this approach:  https://sleeplessbeastie.eu/2017/09/18/how-to-execute-cgi-scripts-using-fcgiwrap/

Answer (score 4):

If you prefer full control in Python:

- Create `/opt/httpbot.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import subprocess

class Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self._handle()

    def do_POST(self):
        self._handle()

    def _handle(self):
        try:
            self.log_message("command: %s", self.path)
            if self.path == '/foo':
                subprocess.run(
                    "cd /opt/bar && GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa' git pull",
                    shell=True,
                )
        finally:
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("content-type", "application/json")
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write('{"ok": true}\r\n'.encode())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HTTPServer(("127.0.0.1", 4242), Handler).serve_forever()
```

- No concurrency/parallelism here, so `httpbot` runs one command at a time, no conflicts.
- Run `apt install supervisor`
- Create `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/httpbot.conf`:

```ini
[program:httpbot]
environment=PYTHONUNBUFFERED="TRUE"
directory=/opt
command=/opt/httpbot.py
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/httpbot.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB
stdout_logfile_backups=10
```

- Add to your nginx server:

```
    location /foo {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4242/foo;
    }
```

- Run:

```bash
chmod u+x /opt/httpbot.py

service supervisor status
# If stopped:
service supervisor start

supervisorctl status
# If httpbot is not running:
supervisorctl update

curl https://example.com/foo
# Should return {"ok": true}

tail /var/log/httpbot.log
# Should show `command: /foo` and the output of shell script
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a hackish way to do it without any additional modules and without FastCGI:

1. Create a systemd `nginxfeeder.socket` service, which will listen on a specified port, i.e. 8765, and invoke nginxfeeder.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Nginx callback status

[Socket]
ListenStream=127.0.0.1:8765
Accept=yes
    
[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

2. Create a corresponding `nginxfeeder@.service` file invoked by this:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/scripts/nginxhandler.sh
StandardError=journal
StandardInput=socket
StandardOutput=socket
User=wwwrun
Group=wwwrun
```

3. Register this with systemd (you don't need to copy scripts to /etc) and start:

```
systemctl enable `pwd`/nginxfeeder.socket
systemctl enable `pwd`/nginxfeeder@.service
systemctl start nginxfeeder.socket
```

4. Test it with `telnet 127.0.0.1 8765` and you should see the output of your script.
5. Now your script is available at 127.0.0.1:8765 and you can use nginx `proxy_pass` directive to have it invoked for a specific URL.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install OpenResty (OpenResty is just an enhanced version of Nginx by means of addon modules ) Refer https://openresty.org/en/getting-started.html  for this
2. Configure aws cli on the instance
3. Write a shell script which download a file from specified S3 bucket
4. Do the required changes in nginx.conf file
5. Restart the nginx server

I have tested the http request using curl and file gets download in `/tmp` directory of respective instance:

```
curl -I http://localhost:8080/
```

OutPut:

```
curl -I http://localhost:8080/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: openresty/1.13.6.2
Date: Tue, 14 Aug 2018 07:34:49 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Connection: keep-alive
```

Content of nginx.conf file:

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log logs/error.log;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    server {
        listen 8080;
        location / {
           default_type text/html;
           content_by_lua '
                ngx.say("<p>hello, world</p>")
           ';
        }

        location / {
            content_by_lua_block{
            os.execute("sh /tmp/s3.sh")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't seen any shell script output and also, it says my file /tmp/s3.sh doesn't exist even though i created that file and it runs when i execute it directly.

Comment: My os.execute writes to stdout (i see it in nginx logs) but I got empty page in browser.

Comment: ngx.say writes to response as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nginx's perl module which is usually part of a repo and can be easily installed. Sample to call system curl command:

```
   location /mint {
       perl '
            sub {
               my $r = shift;
               $r->send_http_header("text/html");
               $r->print(`curl -X POST --data \'{"method":"evm_mine"}\' localhost:7545`);
               return OK;
            }
       '; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the nginx mirror module and proxy_pass it to a web script that runs whatever. In my case I just added this to my main site location, {...

```
mirror /mirror;
mirror_request_body off;
```

and then made a new location called mirror that I had run a php script that executed whatever...

```
location = /mirror {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://localhost/run_script.php;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
    proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
}
```

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_mirror_module.html