# Nginx - execute command on error (5xx gateway errors)

Tags: nginx

I've seen the answers to [nginx-how-to-run-a-shell-script-on-every-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891148/nginx-how-to-run-a-shell-script-on-every-request), but my request is a bit different:

Whenever I have a problem with the back end (Mendix/Java specifically, but  Python/django/plone also involved) which I'm proxying to, I would like to execute a script, but NOT return the results to the browser, ie. it is done asynchronously to the request, and perhaps issue a retry/reload/redirect page, but the important part for me is the script to be run whenever there is a gateway error.

The "need" is to either trigger a restart of the back-end, or issue an error/warning to the sysadmins.

Comment: This blog provides a way to do something similar to what youre asking: https://www.nginx.com/blog/capturing-5xx-errors-debug-server/

Comment: Thank you, that calls a different server, but will see how to amend that if possible for my case(s)

Comment: Did you find any solutions for it?

Comment: @FatemehMajd unfortunately no ;(